# Hash Table rsearching and moving past deleted items

Tags: c, algorithm, search, logic

I am currently working on linear hash tables and trying to create a function which searches throughout my table. I have having a problem with moving past deleted items. I will show below.

Here is my loop to move through the table:

I know that deleted doesnt make sense how it is but it is part of a struct and I simplified it by just typing deleted.

```
while(K != Key && (Key != 0 || deleted != 0))
    {
        i -= Decrement;
        if(i < 0)
        {
            i += hash->size;
        }
        Key = hash->table[i].K;
        count++;
        if(count == hash->size)
        {
            Key = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

So this loop goes through my table. K is the given value I am trying to find. Key is the value the loop finds in each spot as it moves down the table. It is compared to K to stop the loop.

Now my problem comes with the second part of the while loop. When an item is deleted, I set the space to deleted = 1. Also when nothing is set into the the space it is set to 0.

Deleted = 0 when not deleted and deleted = 1 when deleted.

It would have a Key value of 0 and a deleted value of 1 if the space was deleted.

Is if I have a table that looks as follows:

```
[Deleted]<-- starts on this
[5] <-- looking for this
```

When ever it hits a deleted spot it exits the loop and doesnt find the correct value. Can anyone help me with the logic in the parameters of my while loop to make it keep going. Here what I think:

(The Key value does not equal K.) AND (Key does not equal 0 AND key is not deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe due to operator precedence. Try this

```
while(K != Key && ((Key != 0) || (deleted != 0)))
```

`The precedence of != is greater than || so the program behaves unexpectedly, so always try to use brackets when handling such situations.

Comment: Yes, `!=` has **higher** precedence than `||`, but brackets aren't necessary (and the results are perfectly defined). `Key != 0 || deleted != 0` is the same as `(Key != 0) || (deleted != 0)` (in the same way `*` has higher precedence than `+`, thus `5*5+5*5` is the same as `(5*5)+(5*5)`), i.e. this change doesn't do anything.